# Textsum - full of stopwords in decoded results

Tags: tensorflow, textsum

I'm trying to implement the [Tensorflow Textsum model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/textsum) on my own data. The training set contains around 50k articles. I didn't change any default settings in the textsum model. Currently, my 'average loss' is around 1.5 to 3.0. However, the decoded results are lists of 'the', 'of', 'in', 'to' or so.

## decoded

```
of in in and and to to to to to
of a in and and to to to to
cats s s and and and to to
```

## ref

```
rift between officers and residents as killings persist in south bronx
among deaths in 2016, a heavy toll in pop music
kim jong un says north korea is preparing to test long range missile
```

I don't expect too precise results at this stage, but I think even a list of random words is better than 'of in in and and and to to'.

Comment: Maybe you could add why you expect there to be no stop words (if that is the problem - note 100% clear).

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Already edited the problem.